# Well-defined $\xi$-weighted (Euclidean) norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, least-squares

Suppose $\xi$ is a vector, that is used for $\parallel z\parallel_\xi$ calculation. Should every element of $\xi$ be positive, $\xi(i)>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how you define the weighted norm. For
$$\|z\|_\xi = \left(\sum_i z_i^2 \xi_i\right)^{1/2}$$
Then yes, $\xi_i>0$ is required for this to be a true norm. If instead you define it as
$$\|z\|_\xi = \left(\sum_i (\xi_i z_i)^2\right)^{1/2}$$
then the condition is simply $\xi_i\neq 0$.

Comment: What happens if in the first case some of the $\xi_i=0$, but the value inside the parenthesis is greater than zero?

Comment: It is not a true norm in that case. I believe it is a seminorm, however.